# OSX, find full paths of all matches for a file name in sub folders?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I'm going to state with my goal, however I'm starting with the first step.

*I want to find the full path of my iphone apps in their simulator folders then identify which version of iOS and which device type they are. I can do that later steps using the simpholders app, but this is a manual step.
Why? I need to add this path to a shell scripts to run a batch process.*

So firstly, I want to find a all the full paths in sub folders of whatever.app from a top level folder.

On windows I would do...

```
dir c:\windows\*.com /s/b
```

EDIT: including occurences within sub folders or sub folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find /path/to/root -name "whatever.app"`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not at my mac atm, will that produce the full path in sub directories of sub directories too ?

Comment: Yes, it will find all "files" under the entire subdirectory tree under `/path/to/root` that has a name `whatever.app`. You can type `man find` to see other options you can append to the end of the command, say `-type d` to match only directories. And you can use wildcards in place of `"whatever.app"`, such as `"*.app"`.